# Slowness following freeproccache

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I had one that was slow in the app, but fast in SSMS, like in [Sommarskog's query plan mysteries article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#dmvgettingplans).

The query is a search with many parameters that can vary.  What's strange is, when I reindex, it executes in 2 seconds.  Then i call dbcc freeproccache, and it takes 40 seconds, consistently, no matter how many times I execute the sproc again.  If I reindex again, the performance recovers.  If I free the proc cachec, it goes back up to 40  seconds.

How can I get the good execution plan that results from executing right after reindexing to stay in the cache and be available to the application as well?

Comment: At the very least please post your query.  There isn't much to go off of here.  Bonus points for including execution plan.

Comment: Well why are you calling freeproccache after you reindex, and after it seems like you temporarily *had* the right plan?

Comment: Are you able to isolate where your sproc is spending its time? In SQL2008+ Extended Events is a good tool for this. This sounds like parameter sniffing, so a statement-level recompile hint might be in order. Or, you could go whole hog and put "with recompile" on the proc level.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a [parameter sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx) issue.  Parameter sniffing is basically SQL Server using the first set of parameters that you pass in to determine an execution plan that will be used for all future executions.  This can be good if those parameters generate an execution plan that works well for all of the various conditions it will be executing in, but can be a problem sometimes.

One quick way to check this would be to use the  `RECOMPILE` [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) and see fi that speeds things up.  If you decide to go this route, make sure you fully understand the consequences of what you are doing before you put it into a production environment.

Comment: The problem originally looked like this: The query went well in SSMS, but slowly in the application.  I played around with numeric roundabort and arithabort settings and got the same bad performance from ssms that way.  Then tried freeproccache to get ssms back to normal.  That didn't work, and then I found that when I drop and recreate even one of the indexes involved in the query, the sproc call in ssms is very fast, like you said, I have the right plan at that point.  But then if I dump the proc cache, performance goes bad, and I can't get the good plan back until I drop and recreate